# How to evaluate InstanceMethodCallExpressionN

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

How do I evaluate the left-hand side of this binary expression?

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expr = (x) => x.Birthday.AddMinutes(1) > DateTime.UtcNow;
```

If I call

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(expr.Left).Compile().DynamicInvoke()
```

I get the error message "variable 'x' of type '...' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

To be clear, I want to get the value of x.Birthday.AddMinutes(1) which is a InstanceMethodCallExpressionN

Comment: How would you *like* to evaluate it? What value for `x` would you like to supply? What do you hope to achieve by trying to compile only the left-hand side?

Comment: So `((BinaryExpression) expr.Body).Left`? Note that `x` is still unbound in there, so if you want to turn this into something compilable, more work is needed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I can already evaluate the right-hand side. I'm not sure how to evaluate the left which is a InstanceMethodCallExpressionN. It's for translating expression trees into a different representation so I need to extract the value as a constant to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the parameter (`x`) from the original lambda to create a new lambda that uses that parameter.

```
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(((BinaryExpression)expr.Body).Left, expr.Parameters);
var lambdaFunc = lambdaExpr.Compile();
var result = lambdaFunc.DynamicInvoke(new Person() { Birthday = DateTime.Now});
// e.g. 2/12/2020 1:39:12 PM
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The left part of the binary expression is a MethodCallExpression.
So I check and cast accordingly.

```
private void a2()
        {
            // The original expression
            Expression<Func<Person1, bool>> expr = (x) => x.Birthday.AddMinutes(1) > DateTime.UtcNow;

            // Decompose the original expr.
            ParameterExpression param = (ParameterExpression)expr.Parameters[0];
            BinaryExpression operation = (BinaryExpression)expr.Body;
            var leftExpr = operation.Left;

            if(leftExpr is MethodCallExpression)
            {
                MethodCallExpression expression = (MethodCallExpression)leftExpr;
                object result = Expression.Lambda(expression, param).Compile().
                    DynamicInvoke(new Person1() { Birthday = DateTime.Parse("06-03-2020") });
            }
        }
```